# How to create public facebookRequest class ? php facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to get the city graph by facebook php sdk:

```
public static function getPublicGraphObject($Id)
{
  $request = new FacebookRequest(null, 'GET', '/'.$Id);
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  return $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}
```

because the city is public data, there is no need for session ?
unfortunately I get this error `Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given` ? what should I do ?

Comment: Simply _create_ a session and pass it as first parameter – use an app session if you have no logged in user or do not want to make this request “as” the current user.

Comment: How to create app session ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0#newappsession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize the `FacebookRequest` class, you need to pass it a `FacebookSession` instance as first parameter, you can not simply pass `NULL` instead.

If you do not have a current user logged in to your app (and therefor no user session), or want to make a request not on behalf of the current user, but simply “as” your app instead, create a new app session and pass that – the `FacebookSession` class has a [`newAppSession`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0#newappsession) method for that purpose.